# Python Processing large amount of data from excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I've got very hard task to do. I need to process Excel file with 6336 rows x 53 columns. My task is to create program which:

1. Read data from input Excel file.
2. Sort all rows by specific column data, for eg. Sort by A1:A(last)
3. Place columns in new output Excel file by given order, for eg.

```
SaleCity           Branch                   CustomerID       InvoiceNum
Old File           For eg.                  Old File         Merge old file cols
Col[A1:A(last)]    SaleCity='Oklahoma'      Col[M1:M(last)   Col[K1:K(last) &
                   Branch='OKL GamesShop'                    B1:B(last)]
```

4. Save new excel File.

Excel Sample:
[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re190.jpg)
(All data in this post is not real so don't try to hack someone or something :D)

I know that I did not provide any code but to be honest I tried solving it by myself and I don't even know which module I should use. I tried using OpenPyXl and Pandas but there's too much data for my capabilities.

Thank you in advance for any help. If I asked the question in the wrong place, please direct me to the right one.

Edit:
To be clear. I'm not asking for full solution here. What am I asking for is guidance and mentority.

Comment: Sounds like [pandas read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) and to_excel would be useful here

Comment: As @G.Anderson mentioned, you can use `pandas`. Or you can also try `xlrd` module.

Comment: Can you export the file from Excel in CSV format?

Comment: I tried usingpandas read_excel and I even get a Python Dict with that but I was not able to process it cause of large ammount of data. I think that my approach witch Dict is bad cause it will consume too much memory but in the other hand I don;t know how to perform operations on data without storing it in Dict first. Thanks for You interest guys.
@Broseph I think i can do that.

Comment: @EdwardNoga 6.5k rows should be fine with read_excel - it's usually quite slow but should complete ok (it's not much data..)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use PySpark. It is more difficult than pandas, but the parallelization provided will help with yours large excel files.

Or you could also use multiprocessing lib from python to paralelize pandas functions.
https://towardsdatascience.com/make-your-own-super-pandas-using-multiproc-1c04f41944a1